# Ошибка при выполнении алгоритма обменной сортировки на Java

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Совсем недавно начал писать на Java и попробовал реализовать алгоритм обменной сортировки и вот какую ошибку мне выдало: [image]
Как я понимаю, проблема как раз в самой реализации алгоритма, но писал тоже самое на Си, все работало отлично.
Вот сам код программы:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class exchangeSorting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i, j, z;
        int[] A = new int[5];
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            A[i] = 0 + random.nextInt(100);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
                if (A[j] > A[j+1]) {
                    z = A[j];
                    A[j] = A[j+1];
                    A[j+1] = z;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что, на сколько мне известно, в Си, в отличии от Java не выбрасываются исключения при выходе за пределы массива.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могло оно нормально работать в С, чистая случайность... Вернее, UB - при обращении за границами массива.

```
for (j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
        if (A[j] > A[j+1])
```

И к какому элементу вы обращаетесь в `A[j+1]` при `j == A.length-1`?

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо большое. Получается выхожу за границу массива из-за этого и ошибка.